# MySQL | Can not set UTC_TIMESTAMP after ON UPDATE

Tags: mysql

Despite being able to set `UTC_TIMESTAMP` for:

✔   `ALTER TABLE post ADD created_at DATETIME DEFAULT (UTC_TIMESTAMP);`

I haven't been able to set `UTC_TIMESTAMP` for:

✘   `ALTER TABLE post ADD updated_at DATETIME ON UPDATE (UTC_TIMESTAMP) AFTER created_at;`

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(UTC_TIMESTAMP) AFTER created_at'

Comment: Known bug / feature request: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=103228

Comment: @BillKarwin I can't believe this is a thing in 2021!!

Comment: If you're going to use only UTC times anyway, you could set the [timezone to UTC](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html)